# saving and reading multiple objects

Tags: java, swing, jlist

i want to save and read objects in java.

```
private JButton save = new JButton("save");
save.addActionListener(
           new ActionListener(){
              public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0){
                 sauvegarder();}}); 
read();
```

now   these are the methods of reading and saving objects...

method "sauvegarder" for saving ::::

```
  ArrayList<projet> file = new ArrayList<projet> ();


  public void sauvegarder(){

    projet pro = new projet (Integer.parseInt( a1.getText()),a2.getText(),a3.getText(),list1);
        file.add(pro);  

      try {
           FileOutputStream fileOut= new FileOutputStream("LES PROJETS.txt");
           ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut) ;

           for (projet a:file)
              out.writeObject(a);
           out.close();
        }

           catch(Exception e) 
           {e.printStackTrace();}

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                " ^_^ FILE SAVED ^_^","save file",
                JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);}
```

method "read" for reading :::

```
 ArrayList<projet> file1 = new ArrayList<projet> ();
 JList l1 = new JList();


 public void read(){
  ObjectInputStream in = null;

     try {
        FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream("LES PROJETS.txt");
        in = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn) ;
        while (true){      
           try{
              projet c =( projet) in.readObject();
              file1.add(c);}
              catch(EOFException ex){// end of file case

                 break;}
        }}

        catch(Exception e)
        {e.printStackTrace();}
     finally{ 
        try { in.close();
        } 
           catch (IOException e) { 
              e.printStackTrace(); } }}
     l1= new JList (file1.toArray());
           }
```

now reading and saving are working properly ,but the problem is that the two arraylists are empty !!when I write file.size()-->0 !! although I was saved objects....and the file "les projets . txt " contains the objects that I saved  ,and the JList show me the object in the arraylist !!!

plus  when I want to save more objects(projet) ,the first objects, that I saved them ,are removed and the new objects are saved...
could someone help me please ?!

Comment: You're doing something weird elsewhere in your code.  You realize the "file" arraylist and the "file1" arraylist are different lists right?

Comment: @Taylor yes they are differents! where is the weird something!

Comment: Was that the problem?

Comment: first the "file" is empty !!!!
second when I want to save more objects(projet) ,the first objects, that I saved them ,are removed and the new objects are saved...

Comment: You need to show code that calls `sauvegarder`

Comment: I don't understand !!! 
what is the solution?

Comment: I don't know.  The problem is in code you haven't included in your question.

Comment: @Taylor which part of code?

Comment: Seriously?  "You need to show code that calls sauvegarder"

Comment: @peeskillet okk ,so the ArrayList file now is not important!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're trying to write with this list `file`

```
ArrayList<projet> file = new ArrayList<projet> ();
...
for (projet a:file)
     out.writeObject(a);
```

which is empty because you never add anything to it. The list that *has* the data is `file1`

```
ArrayList<projet> file1 = new ArrayList<projet> ();
```

You need to be writing the data from `file1` not `file`